# Background of CustomView in Android

Tags: android

I want to doodle images so for this I am using CustomView. Now I can draw on the screen but with white background.I am also getting Image from gallery in form of bitmap but i have no idea that how to set background of my custom view with this bitmap.

looking forward to valuable suggestions.
Also, I know about set background method can be used here.But this method only takes drawable as argument.I have no idea how to convert bitmap to drawable.

Comment: Can you share some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a bitmap to a drawable, use this:

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

This uses BitmapDrawable to convert any `Bitmap` variable into a new `Drawable` variable. I hope this helps.